# Battery lasts a month on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, battery

iMac power supply died, and I decided to replace instead of fix.  The day after I ordered the replacement, my iPad screen failed to light the screen.  That I intend to fix, but I didn’t want to touch until I could load the backups form the old disk drive onto the new computer.

Took nearly a month (long story) for the new computer to arrive, during which the iPad has been untouched on the coffee table.  Every once in a while, including today, it makes the new mail sound.

And I just confirmed with the iPhone that it is still online and reporting its location.

When it was in full use, it was down to 20% or less every night.  I expect sleep to use less power, but that really surprises me.  **Is that big a difference typical?**

Comment: I guess the screen really accounts for most of the energy usage.

Answer (score 1):

It sure is!

http://youtu.be/GX2hy-L94T0?t=9m13s
Here's a video of Steve Jobs talking about the original iPad's battery.

All iPads have 10 hours of battery life but 1 month of standby time.

Comment: Wasn't that before push notifications? I'd expect a large drop in battery life with notifications running.

Comment: Even if standby includes downloading lots of mail and reporting it’s location for Find My iPad?